# Perl+Postgresql: a function does not return a value if RAISE NOTICE is present

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

I noticed that when I call a PL/PgSQL or PL/Perl function from a Perl script using DBI, it does not return a value if a RAISE NOTICE or elog(NOTICE) is used in the function. To illustrate:

A simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."table1" (
  "fld" INTEGER
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

A simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."function1" () RETURNS integer AS
$body$
DECLARE
  myvar INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO myvar fld FROM table1 LIMIT 1;
  RETURN myvar;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

A piece of Perl script:

```
use DBI;
...
my $ref = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref('SELECT function1()');
print $$ref[0];
```

As it is, it prints the value from the table.

But I get no result if I add RAISE NOTICE as follows:

```
SELECT INTO myvar fld FROM table1 LIMIT 1;
RAISE NOTICE 'Testing';
RETURN myvar;
```

Am I missing something or such behavior is by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [`client_min_messages`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) setting in your database server's `postgresql.conf` file.  From the PostgreSQL 8.3 docs:

> `client_min_messages` (string)
>
> > Controls which message levels are sent to the client. Valid values are `DEBUG5`, `DEBUG4`, `DEBUG3`, `DEBUG2`, `DEBUG1`, `LOG`, `NOTICE`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, `FATAL`, and PANIC. Each level includes all the levels that follow it. The later the level, the fewer messages are sent. The default is `NOTICE`. Note that `LOG` has a different rank here than in `log_min_messages`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this, using Debian's Perl 5.10, DBI 1.605 and DBD::Pg 2.8.7 against PostgreSQL 8.3.7. I get the notice printed out as expected.

```
steve@steve@[local] =# create or replace function public.function1() returns integer language 'plpgsql' as $$ declare myvar integer; begin select into myvar fld from table1 limit 1; raise notice 'Testing'; return myvar; end; $$;
CREATE FUNCTION
steve@steve@[local] =#
[1]+  Stopped                 psql --cluster 8.3/steve
steve@arise:~$ DBI_TRACE=1 perl -MData::Dumper -MDBI -e '$dbh = DBI->connect(qw|dbi:Pg:dbname=steve;port=5433;host=/tmp steve steve|, {RaiseError=>1,PrintError=>0}); print Data::Dumper->new([$dbh->selectcol_arrayref("SELECT function1()")], [qw|result|])->Dump'
    DBI 1.605-ithread default trace level set to 0x0/1 (pid 5739) at DBI.pm line 273 via -e line 0
    Note: perl is running without the recommended perl -w option
    -> DBI->connect(dbi:Pg:dbname=steve;port=5433;host=/tmp, steve, ****, HASH(0x1c9ddf0))
    -> DBI->install_driver(Pg) for linux perl=5.010000 pid=5739 ruid=1000 euid=1000
       install_driver: DBD::Pg version 2.8.7 loaded from /usr/lib/perl5/DBD/Pg.pm
    <- install_driver= DBI::dr=HASH(0x1e06a68)
    !! warn: 0 CLEARED by call to connect method
    <- connect('dbname=steve;port=5433;host=/tmp', 'steve', ...)= DBI::db=HASH(0x1fd8e08) at DBI.pm line 638
    <- STORE('RaiseError', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 690
    <- STORE('PrintError', 0)= 1 at DBI.pm line 690
    <- STORE('AutoCommit', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 690
    <- STORE('Username', 'steve')= 1 at DBI.pm line 693
    <> FETCH('Username')= 'steve' ('Username' from cache) at DBI.pm line 693
    <- connected('dbi:Pg:dbname=steve;port=5433;host=/tmp', 'steve', ...)= undef at DBI.pm line 699
    <- connect= DBI::db=HASH(0x1fd8e08)
    <- STORE('dbi_connect_closure', CODE(0x1da2280))= 1 at DBI.pm line 708
NOTICE:  Testing
    <- selectcol_arrayref('SELECT function1()')= ( [ '2' ] ) [1 items] at -e line 1
$result = [
            '2'
          ];
```

I suggest isolating your problem to a small script (like above) and running it with `DBI_TRACE` set fairly high any seeing what differences you see. Maybe also looking at the release notes for DBD::Pg and seeing if they mention it maybe having been confused by these in the past. With `DBI_TRACE=10` I see this:

```
PQexec
Begin pg_warn (message: NOTICE:  Testing
 DBIc_WARN: 1 PrintWarn: 1)
NOTICE:  Testing
End pg_warn
Begin _sqlstate
```

So you should be looking for something like that in your own output.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use DBD::PgPP since postgres runs on another box. Tried adding DBI->trace(),  but I still can't see neither result nor notice. Setting client_min_messages=error in postgresql.conf actually helped.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like the DBD::PgPP driver doesn't cope with the message, so you're working around the problem. You can use DBD::Pg to talk to postgres on another machine as well--- you just need libpq installed to use DBD::Pg, not the whole server build.

Comment: Yes, using DBD::PgPP 0.06 reproduces the problem: I suggest you report it to the maintainer.

Comment: After all, I had to install DBD::Pg anyway, since PgPP produced  segfault when working with large queries (>300K). Will see how it handles notices.